# Interpolate string c# 6.0 and Stylecop

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2015, stylecop, c#-6.0

I am using Stylecop version : 4.7.49.0

Has anyone used the latest interpolate string functionality in c# 6.0

example

```
var totalUnits = GetUnitsGetTotalIssuedShares(myId);
var testString = $"Test Units :{totalUnits}, have been shipped.";
```

When I build i get the stylecop error SA0102 - because stylecop cant parse the file. It doesn't seem like there is a new version of stylecop that can handle 6.0 yet?

> error :SA0102: A syntax error has been discovered in file

Is there anyway around this error?

Comment: Stylecop isn't part of Visual Studio and the latest version is 1 year old. You'd have to upgrade it to a newer version, once it becomes available

Comment: Just wondered if there was a way to suppress this SA0102

Comment: Try the Roslyn-based implementation of StyleCop rules: https://github.com/DotNetAnalyzers/StyleCopAnalyzers

Comment: Style Cop looks to be a dead project. The last stable release was January 2012. https://stylecop.codeplex.com/releases/view/79972

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is StyleCop 4.7 compatible with C# 6.0 code](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35113492/is-stylecop-4-7-compatible-with-c-sharp-6-0-code)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

SA0102 is an [internal stylecop error](https://stylecop.codeplex.com/discussions/213021) so can't be supressed or ignored via a settings file.

You can suppress a file from stylecop by finding the filename and changing the section to this in the csproj:

```
<Compile Include="<filename>.cs">
  <ExcludeFromStyleCop>True</ExcludeFromStyleCop>
</Compile>
```

You can get the same effect by right clicking on the offending file and selecting "exclude from style cop" if you have the StyleCop plugin installed. It currently needs to be 4.7.50 alpha for Visual Studio 2015.

---

The more modern way of doing this is to make use of the Analyzers feature of Visual Studio 2015, with [StyleCop.Analyzers](https://github.com/DotNetAnalyzers/StyleCopAnalyzers).

[image]

Moving to Stylecop.Analyzers, this would add them into the rules in the relevant *.ruleset file (same place as CodeAnalysis rules)

[image]

and you can run them via

[image]

Which has the same effect as right click **Run StyleCop**:

I.e. giving:

[image]

This will have better support for C# 6, as StyleCop 4.7.50, which Supports Visual Studio 2015,  is in alpha and does not yet support C# 6.

Comment: I am not sure this is a great solution to disable style analysis per file that uses 6.0 features.  Unfortunately this version of StylCop (the last version) is just not compatible with C# 6.0, so you either have to turn it off or hopefully someone might update and distribute a patch.

Comment: Um... sorry? Perhaps the [style cop project](http://stylecop.codeplex.com/) would be a better vent for your frustrations than me.

Comment: Sadly, Stylecop.Analyzers does not offer much in the way of R# integration, and can only be evaluated on build, which makes it unusable for any mid-large scale project.

Answer (score 1):

StyleCop should be able to handle C# 6 now:

Changes Beta 4.7.51: Added initial (and untested) support for C# 6.0 syntax

So with stable build 4.7.54 or later you should not encounter this anymore: http://stylecop.codeplex.com/releases/view/621306

Comment: No, apparently not, I just upgraded to 4.7.54 and I still have the same issue. :( However, only when I use complicated $@ string interpolations. Most notably: When you contain expressions with parentheses in the brackets, not variables.

Comment: Seems like they overlooked some edge cases. You should open an issue with some concrete examples to let them know (http://stylecop.codeplex.com/workitem/list/basic).

Comment: I have 4.7.58.3 and still have an issue with string interpolation + literal, e.g., `string x = $@"{var1} is not a number, {var2} is";`

Comment: it looks like it is being caused by using code with nested quotes inside of interpolation, such as `string x = $@"Today is {myDate.ToString(@"MM/dd/yyyy")}.";`  And the previous issue was closed, as it was a duplicate of this one: https://stylecop.codeplex.com/workitem/7721

Comment: UPDATE: 4.7.58.3 was the version of the nuget package I was using for stylecop libraries, so that wasn't the correct version.  I'll have to update to the official stylecop extension on codeplex.