# Is StyleCop 4.7 compatible with C# 6.0 code

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2013, visual-studio-2015, stylecop

I installed StyleCop 4.7 for developing customized rules, to analyze our C# code.

We write the code in Visual Studio 2015. I can analyze my C# 5.0 (Visual Studio 2013) code, and I get correct response, but when I analyze my C# 6.0 (Visual Studio 2015) code, StyleCop raises an exception for my rules.

Now my question is:

> Is StyleCop 4.7 compatible with C# 6.0 code? If not, do we have any solution?

Comment: Do you mean C# 6.0, there is no such thing as C# 2015 as far as I'm aware. Or do you mean Visual Studio 2015? The official site might be useful: https://stylecop.codeplex.com/

Comment: thanks for your comment,  C# code that we can write in visual studio 2015

Answer (score 11):

**TL;DR - Yes. StyleCop 4.7 was updated to be compatible with C# 6 starting with 4.7.51 (Beta) released on 13th March 2016.**
<sub>There was a [handover to new custodians](https://stylecop.codeplex.com/discussions/644152) back in January 2016, and a new version 4.7.50 alpha has been released 3rd Feb 2016, but as yet does not include C# 6 support.

4.7.51 (Beta) was released on 13th March 2016 and the latest stable is 4.7.54 released May 13th.</sub>

---

Here are three other options that work with Visual Studio 2015:

### 1. Visual StyleCop

[Visual StyleCop](https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/cac2a05b-6eb6-4fa2-95b9-1f8d011e6cae), is an extension to Visual Studio. This gives you the right click functionality into Visual Studio 2015 that installing StyleCop gave you for 2013 and below.

This is available by adding an extension into Visual Studio:

[image: Visual StyleCop]

It is an active project and will give you StyleCop on C# 6 features. There is a package - [Visual-StyleCop.MSBuild](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Visual-StyleCop.MSBuild/), that will give you MSBuild integration.

It is possible to write [custom rules](https://github.com/Visual-Stylecop/Visual-StyleCop/wiki/Authoring-a-Custom-StyleCop-Rule) with Visual StyleCop.

### 2. StyleCop Analyzers

[StyleCop.Analyzers](https://github.com/DotNetAnalyzers/StyleCopAnalyzers) are built upon Rosalyn and make use of the Analyzers feature of Visual Studio 2015. They are available on NuGet:

[image: StyleCop.Analyzers NuGet Package]

This would add them into the rules in the relevant `*.ruleset` file (same place as CodeAnalysis rules, accessible from the project page:)

[image: Project Page]

giving:

[image: RuleSet Example]

and you can run them via

[image: Run Analyzerss Example]

Which has the same effect as right click, **Run StyleCop**, used on previous versions and with Visual StyleCop.

Giving:

[image: Example Errors]

The source code is [available on GitHub](https://github.com/DotNetAnalyzers/StyleCopAnalyzers), so adding custom rules should be possible.

### 3. Resharper, with StyleCop by Jetbrains

Install:

- Resharper 10.0.1
- StyleCop by JetBrains 4.8

[image: R# StyleCop Plugin]

Which gives this in R# options:
[image: R# Options]

This gives you syntax highlighting, but no right click run, and no build integration. Additionally, R# is not a free product.

You can extend it using plugins, but it doesn't feel as customizable as the other two options presented.

Comment: Note that last option has no c#6 support

Comment: Update: Beta 4.7.51 has C# 6 support according to the change log. So the current stable build should now support C# 6.

Answer (score 0):

Version 4.7.51 and later should support C# 6:

> Added initial (and untested) support for C# 6.0 syntax
>
> http://stylecop.codeplex.com/releases/view/620339

So the current stable build should support it, too: http://stylecop.codeplex.com/releases